# What can I do to improve quality of sound recording?

Tags: sound

I have an issue with a sound recording I made with my Olympus LS-12.

The recorder is recording a constant unknown sound at about 10kHz. The sound is visible in the sonagram below as a faint dark band.

[I uploaded a .wav file made with my Olympus LS-12 to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4b3was8807jlr9f/Chaffinch.wav?dl=0)

Can anyone suggest what this noise is and how I can get rid of it? I've tried adjusting the gain of the recorder and recording away from my phone and computer, but this hasn't solved the problem.

[image]

I covered the microphones of the recorder with hands, to try to determine if the unknown sound is internal. This was the result:

[image]

Comment: "buzzing": this might be a language barrier, but to my understaning (I'm not a native English speaker myself) 10 kHz will definitely not sound "buzzing" but more "feeping" to the human ear. Go and use anything to create a 10 kHz tone. Are you *sure* this is what you hear?

Comment: and the vertical lines are broadband. Without knowing anything further about them, and with your time axis being far, far, to rough to say anything for sure, I'd assume they sound like white noise or more probable "clicks".

Comment: That recorder is high quality; you may have a defective one. Alternatives: the strange sound is actually present when you record; or the software you're using can't read 25 bit/sample data correctly.

Comment: Are there any other electronics, such as a CRT or anything with a power supply, battery or battery charger in the recording environment?

Comment: can we hear a piece of that audio please?

Comment: I'd demand even more than @OlliNiemitalo : can we get the raw data? Any Audio compression will probably get rid of most of the artifacts you see.

Comment: **wait**. What's your recording format? The LS-12 *supports* recording as MP3, even at very low bit rates. And that might seriously hurt your signal.

Comment: recording format is wav. What would you recommend to use?

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo how can I upload a wav file?

Comment: @luciano perhaps freesound.org

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo wav file uploaded to freesound.org and question edited. Hope this helps.

Comment: @luciano the link doesn't seem to work

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo works for me, but there's a note saying the file hasn't been moderated. Would this prevent you from accessing the file?

Comment: I guess so. Sorry, it was not a very good suggestion then.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo I've uploaded a wav file to Dropbox. Can you access this file?

Comment: I am far, far away from being an audio expert, but are you sure that there actually *is* a band? As I see your spectrogram, the "dark band" may be perfectly normal, but is framed by sharper low-intensity bands (approx. at 7-8 kHz and 11 kHz). So maybe you have a defective bandpass or something like that in your hardware? Is there a way to measure *only* noise (e.g. by detaching or electronically blanking the microphone)?

Comment: @M529 I covered the microphones of the recorder with hands, to try to determine if the unknown sound is internal. I've uploaded the spectrogram to the question. Surely there is something strange going on here. Yes?

Comment: @luciano yes it works now from dropbox!

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo so what's your verdict…?

Comment: @luciano it is difficult to say. The band seems to follow the lower-frequency audio so it might be just a large-gain band in the microphone frequency response. I'd try another microphone to be sure.

Comment: I came to conclusion the device must be defective so got it swapped for a new device. Amazingly, the new device has the exact same problem...very disappointing.